# Как определенный элемент массива вставить на первое место?

Tags: javascript, массивы, api

Есть лексикографически отсортированный массив объектов, получаемый из api, где есть одно из свойств - имя города(Name)
Мне необходимо отсортировать, что бы сначала шел город, который мне нужен, а все остальные по алфавиту.

```
const result = response.data
          result.sort( (a, b) => {
            return a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name)
          });
```

Можно как-нибудь задать такой порядок сортировки, что бы сначала на первом месте был какой-то определенный город, скажем "Москва", а затем всё остальные элементы отсортировались лексикографически?
Я пытался сделать что-то типо того:

```
if(a.Name === 'Москва') {
return 1;
}
if (a.Name < b.Name) {
  return -1;
  }
return 0;
```

Но это совсем не то...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно так

```js
const arr = [
  {Name: 'НеМосква1'},
  {Name: 'НеМосква2'},
  {Name: 'Москва'},
  {Name: 'НеМосква3'}
];

var result = arr.sort( (a, b) => {
        if(a.name == "Москва") return -1;
        if(b.name == "Москва") return 1;
        return a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name)
    })

console.log(result);
```

Comment: И ваше решение тоже подошло... Чёрт, чувствую себя идиотом.
Что бы подтянуть, что бы мне решения также быстро приходили в голову? Простая ведь задача, сам понимаю, но не хотелось ради этого создавать циклы, какие-то условия... хотелось также лаконично, как у вас.

Comment: @StockholmSyndrom Ваше решение было по сути верным, просто чуть-чуть недодумали.

Comment: Целый день я "недодумал" -_-

Answer (score 5):

```js
const result = [
{Name: 'НеМосква1'},
{Name: 'НеМосква2'},
{Name: 'Москва'},
{Name: 'НеМосква3'}
];

// Сначала отсортируйте 
result.sort((a, b) => a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name));

//Потом поставьте нужный город на первое место:
const [item] = result.splice(result.findIndex(a => a.Name === 'Москва'), 1);
result.splice(0, 0, item)
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Боже, я бился над этой задачей целый день, а вы так просто и быстро её решили... Причём, я первый раз вижу такой метод, как findIndex.
Но не суть, большое спасибо.

Comment: @StockholmSyndrom findIndex тут не принципиален - можно и indexOf использовать, или обычным циклом пройтись и так найти, с тем же результатом

Comment: Спасибо за вашу правку. Как раз хотел именно так свой ответ отредактировать, а вы уже сделали.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Люблю, когда код работает)